# RelativeLayout margins

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Let's say my current simulator has 480px width.
I add a button to the screen in position 460dp
What will happen if the user's device has 400px width?
Does the button go out of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can test this out in the emulator,  when you set it in AVD manager, you can specify the pixels etc for the device.